# How are the number of levels calculated in a nested random effect within Linear Mixed Model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am testing various linear mixed models (in R using `lmer()`)and am concerned about the lack of levels in one of my parameters, and how it influences the results.

**Design**

I have a continuous variable being tested against categorical Species.

There are generally 10's to many more Specimens per Species.

Each Specimen has a possible 16 teeth (though I currently ignore left and right and condense this to 8 levels)

Each molar has 4 possible positions from which a measurement is taken i.e. 4 levels.

Typically, there are 2 to 5 measurements/specimen though it varies from 1 to 8.

---

Since there are multiple measurements per specimen, theoretically the model's random effect structure should ideally be:

`Variable ~ Species + (1 : Specimen/Tooth/Position) + fixedFactor1 + andOrFixedFactor2etc`

At the bare minimum, of course `(1 | Specimen)` is used. I am variously testing other models with these random factors e.g. `(1 | Specimen/Tooth), (1| Tooth), (1 | Position), (1 | Tooth/Position),  even (1 | Specimen/Position)` etc. and looking at AIC and R2 etc.

It is noted that `(1 | Position)` has only 4 levels and is therefore likely problematic. **I am mainly wondering how the lack of levels works within the nested random effects?** How do I calculate whether there are sufficient levels *when nested*? What should I look for in the resultant statistics that ensures against problems such as over-fitting?

Comment: Why do you think having only 4 levels is "likely problematic"? 

As for overfitting, it seems to me that that would be a problem if there were too many levels, not too few.

Comment: It's a common rule of thumb that I have seen many times that you should have at least 5 to 6 levels within a random effect. @ben-bolker faq probably says something about it
https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html
Also you can search for Silk et al. 2020 Perils and pitfalls of mixed-effects
regression models in biology.
So if it is nested, what is the overall amount of levels?

Comment: Are the different teeth interchangeable between species, and the different positions interchangeable between teeth? In that case, you may actually have crossed, not nested random effects.

Comment: Each individual Specimen has only it's own teeth. A Tooth is labeled as per its position. e.g. RM3 or Lm2 would represent Right Upper Molar 3, and Left lower molar 2 respectively. Similarly, there are 4 homologous Positions on each tooth measured.

Comment: Didn't find this before, but it has just come up in the side bar and seems to answer the question, in that the "top" parameter is the one that needs a minimum number of levels. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281159/minimum-number-of-repeated-measures-and-levels-per-nested-random-effect?rq=1